# What is the difference between controlling and computational kernels?

Tags: parallelization, kernel, licensing

I have just dowloaded Mma 11.3 with a trial licence. In the download page you can see:

[image]

That I can use 2 controlling kernels and 4 computing kernels.

What is the difference between controlling and computational kernels?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/36293).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, the number of "controlling kernels" means how many instances of Mathematica you can run.

"Computing kernels" is how many subkernels may run when using `Parallel...` operations, i.e. how many CPU cores you can make use of.

Here's the explanation from Wolfram:

- http://support.wolfram.com/kb/36293